# Improve speed of very simple OpenCL kernel

Tags: performance, opencl

Tomorrow I have a test covering OpenCL. We have some example test but no solution for this.
Given is this code:

```
void scalar_add(int n, double *a, double *b, double *result) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

The first task is to write an OpenCL kernel. So my solution:

```
__kernel void scalar_add(
                          __global double *a,
                          __global double *b,
                          __global double *result
) {
       size_t i = get_global_id(0;)
       result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
```

For each element I read one time from A, one from B and write one time to C. I don't see how I can use private or local memory to improve the speed.
The next question is on how to improve the speed with one simple change ("Welche kleine Änderung könnte auf einer Standard-Grafikkarte zu einer deutlichen Leistungssteigerung führen?"). **Is there a way to improve the speed?**

The kernel only reads from A and B so maybe this can be used. I tried using "__local" for arguments A and B instead but this won't compile or run.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to batch the computations together as the kernel is only one computation. So compute several elements inside one kernel to improve coherence and reduce overhead when dispatching kernels. Whether this counts as "one simple change" i don't know..

Comment: In many GPUs using vector types will not help, but will actually generate memory access patterns that do not coalesce well.  And at the same time the arithmetic intensity here is so low, that memory bandwidth will be the limit anyway. Here the best performance hint would actually be: do not use the GPU, do the scalar add using SIMD instructions on the CPU. Maybe the answer is replace double with float?

Comment: @JanLucas [wat](http://reactionimage.org/img/gallery/1968804931.jpg)

Comment: @Hubert: Maximizing the amount of data in flight is often a good idea, but here it is unlikely to help. This kernel is going to use such a small number of registers that you will get perfect occupancy anyway and every thread will already produce 16(read)+8(write) bytes in flight. We can use little's law to calculate how many bytes in flight we need(example for K20): 208 GB/s * 300 Cycles / (706 MCycle/s) =  88 kB in flight needed. Full occupancy on K20 is 13*2048 Threads,  so  3.3 bytes inflight per thread are required -> we use all our memory bandwidth as more 8 bytes per thread are in flight

Comment: Using floats would reduce the required bandwidth by two and at the same time, the arithmetic throughput for floats in much higher than doubles in almost all GPUs (at least double, but often 8x-32x)

Answer (score 0):

The code below should speed it up a bit for you. You need to call it with a single work group. Try group sizes which are a multiple of 32 -- 64 is usually good. Trial and error is a pretty good way of finding the group size sweet spot for your hardware. I am assuming you are using a GPU for this kernel.

I also added maxSize as the upper limit of the loop counter, which should be equal the length of your vectors. You can pass it in as a param, or code it as a constant if you want.

```
__kernel void scalar_add(
                          __global double *a,
                          __global double *b,
                          __global double *result
) 
{
    size_t gid = get_global_id(0);
    size_t groupSize = get_global_size(0);
    for(int i = gid; i< maxSize; i+= groupSize){
        result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

What is happening differently is memory coalescing. as each work item reads its next elements, the reads are combined on a low-level by the hardware. You should be able to get 32 bytes or more with each read, so 4 double values for the price of 1.

Comment: Did you mean get_local_size(0) instead? Because with get_global_size we can access indices which are out of bounds.

Comment: global is correct. This is only meant to be called with one work group, so both would have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The one noticable latency here is kernel overhead. One kernel execution just for a '+' is overkill(but still faster) unless it is already in gpu(not fed from cpu to gpu and has much headroom to optimize).

If it is gpu, then **you can simply move this addition operation to another kernel** and gain some time around hundreds of microseconds to several milliseconds. Of course this is applicable when the other kernel items is completely independent from their neighbours' results since there is no synchronization for whole item array (only compute unit-wide sync is done, not all items)

```
__kernel void scalar_add(
                          __global double *a,
                          __global double *b,
                          __global double *otherParameters

) 
{
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    double result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    // other computations that are independent from neighbours' result 
    // or a,b are not dependant from other things of neighbour items.
    // or
    otherParameters[i]=sin(result[i]);  // ok for example
    otherParameters[i]=cos(result[i+1]) // not ok 
}
```

If consecutive kernels seem to be dependent, try to decompose one of them into two lighter weight components and one of them has to be independent from this addition and other part has to be independent from a third kernel and merging both component should give two instead of three kernel executions. Such decomposition could look like:

```
  // 3 unbalanced kernels
  c=a+b                        // old 1st kernel

  d[i]=sin(c[i+1])+cos(c[i-1]) // old 2nd kernel but dependent to neighbours

  e[i]=raytrace(d[i]);         // old 3rd kernel that is time consuming

  // 2 more balanced kernels     
  c=a+b;                         // new kernel-1
  d0[i]=sin(c[i]);               // new kernel-1 (decomposed 2nd old-kernel part 1)


  d1[i]=cos(c[i]);               // new kernel-2 (decomposed 2nd old-kernel part 2)
  e[i+1]=raytrace(d1[i]+d2[i+2]);// new kernel-2
```

If you can do this, you can get rid of unnecessary global memory accesses to *result array.